# How do I make deleted emails go to the Outlook Trash, not just Gmail trash?

Tags: email, gmail, imap, microsoft-outlook-2013, gmail-imap

I use Outlook 2013 with four email accounts on my notebook computer (Windows 8.1). For three of the accounts, every email I delete is sent to a Trash or Deleted folder in Outlook where I can recover it.  However, in the account coming from Gmail, once the email is deleted in Outlook, it is gone from Outlook. It does not get moved to a Trash or Deleted folder.

All accounts are IMAP. The other three accounts that are working properly are connected with domains of mine (jim@myOwnDomain.com). I found a lot on the Internet about Gmail syncing problems, but none addressed this issue. I'm not sure this is a sync issue. It may be solved by some setting in Outlook, but I have had no luck finding or researching such a setting.

Does anyone have an idea how to have deleted emails remain in my Outlook Trash or Deleted folder so I can recover them on my computer without going online?